# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception react-native using firebase

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

After setting up a react-native project (react-native-starter-kit-instamobile), ran `npm install` followed by `run-android`. I am getting the a `build error`.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.

  > The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.1.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
  >   The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.3,16.0.3]], but resolves to 16.0.6. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: Did you check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies, as the log suggests? Add the dependency tree to the question, if you can. It looks like there is some version mismatch in your dependency listing. Also, see if the dependencies have been set to latest versions.